# How To Use Ruby Which is Installed on Self Hosted Runner Of Github Workflow {ruby/setup-ruby }

Tags: ruby, continuous-integration, yaml, github-actions, building-github-actions

I have a self hosted runner for Git hub workflow ,which requires Ruby for the execution .. I tried to use  [ruby/setup-ruby](https://github.com/ruby/setup-ruby)  which is a prebuilt ruby ..But when I use that it gives me a error as below

- Unable to locate executable file: 7z. Please verify either the file
  path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by
  the PATH environment variable. Also verify the file has a valid
  extension for an executable file.

my yml file related to setting up prebuilt ruby is as follows

```
- uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
    env:
      ImageOS : win19
    with:
      ruby-version: '2.6.5'
```

[image]

- So I  have installed ruby on the server manually. Now I want to use
  that manually  installed  Ruby instance inside my Yml file..  Any advise?

i have added 7zip to my environmental variables and verified that its added as follows

[image]

the service which is  used to communicate my runner with GitHub also works fine as it shows my runner state correctly as follows even I am not executing any workflow action on it..

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Install *7-Zip* on your runner, add the directory, that contains `7z.exe`, to the `PATH` environment variable and restart the runner service so it picks up the updated `PATH` environment variable.

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324) for more details on updating the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: thank you for the response..i tried adding the path. And i verified that the 7zip is added to environmental variable through the CMD by hitting 7z ..but still the error exists.

Comment: Did you set the path variable for the user that ist running the GitHub Actions Runner?

Comment: i am not aware of it..can you please provide me a link to follow it..

Comment: It depends how you set it up. Did you follow https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/adding-self-hosted-runners#adding-a-self-hosted-runner-to-a-repository ? In step 6 there is a note about setting up the runner as a Windows service. Did you do that?

Comment: yes i did that. And the service is running fine..i even tried running the workflow without using ruby..and it generated the apk without any issue..

Comment: the issue is i need ruby to decode my secret keys and access loggings which are encrypted.

Comment: Check in the Windows services under which user the GitHub runner service is running. Make sure that the PATH for this user is setup correctly.

Comment: windows service is listed correctly for the user as i was able to generate artifacts without ruby..any other suggestions

Comment: Have you restarted the service after setting the PATH variable?

Comment: No..i did not..you mean after setting the  7zip path , do  i need to restart GitHub runner service ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. After updating the PATH env variable restart the GitHub runner service.

Comment: it did not work..i tried restarting the github service too..but no luck..but after restarting the github service i am getting following error now .. " Parameter 'commandLine' cannot be null or empty."

Comment: According to your screenshot above you overwrote your %PATH% variable instead of appending the 7-Zip path to it.

Comment: can you please guide me how to correctly append it ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-a-directory-to-the-path-environment-variable-in-windows